# AFL warning: Last new path : none yet (odd, check syntax!)

Tags: security, fuzzing, american-fuzzy-lop

I have this warning

> (Last new path : none yet (odd, check syntax!))

in red after I try to fuzzing a file. I have no idea why it happens and I googled with no answers.

My command is like:

```
afl-fuzz -i testcases/ -o findings/ tcpdump-4.6.2/tcpdump -nr @@
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It usually means that your command line doesn't actually read the file. Try running it without afl-fuzz, substituting `@@` with a path to a file from the `testcases` directory. Hopefully tcpdump's message will tell you what is wrong.

In the future, you might get more attention on the [afl-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/afl-users/) mailing list. Try that if you're not getting any help on SO.

Comment: Wow, it has been months. I didn't expect anyone will really answer this, thanks. It happens sometimes, my guess is lack of library to successfully build the target.