# AFL "(odd, check syntax!) "

Tags: c, warnings, fuzzing, pngquant, american-fuzzy-lop

I am trying to fuzz [pngquant](https://github.com/kornelski/pngquant) using [AFL](https://github.com/google/AFL) and noticed that I am seeing the `odd, check syntax!` warning. A [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625699/afl-warning-last-new-path-none-yet-odd-check-syntax) says that AFL is probably not reading the input file I specified. I am able to invoke `pngquant` by providing the png file located in the same input sample directory I used while fuzzing with AFL.

The AFL command I executed is:

```
afl-fuzz -i ./in-filtered -o ./out -x ./dictionary/png.dict -- pngquant @@
```

The [AFL documentation](https://github.com/google/AFL/blob/master/docs/status_screen.txt) mentions that the `odd, check syntax!` warning may pop up when AFL is not able to find new paths.

Additionally, I notice that the warning pops up as soon as AFL begins using the `havoc` fuzzing strategy, the images below show that the cycle counts start incrementing as soon as the fuzzer begins using `havoc`.

[image: AFL begins fuzzing]

[image: AFL shows warning when fuzzing with havoc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of incorrect usage of pngquant.

When using pngquant, it produces an output file with your results, when you do it twice you will encounter an error:

```
➜  pngquant git:(master) ✗ ./pngquant  ./test/img/metadata.png
➜  pngquant git:(master) ✗ ./pngquant  ./test/img/metadata.png
error: './test/img/metadata-fs8.png' exists; not overwriting
```

AFL has no chance to explore the target, since it gets blocked every time.

After a quick look, the easiest fix is like this:

```
afl-fuzz -i ./in -o ./out -- ./pngquant -f -- @@
```

This forces pngquant to overwrite the resultfile and therefore enables afl-fuzz. However, be aware that this produces a lot of IO. So try to circumvent this using `/dev/null` or similar tricks.

Happy fuzzing!